# return function doesn't render in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I'm trying to implement a shopping cart in React. I've created a context for my cart that handles the quantity purchased and it works fine. However, I have an issue with displaying the data from the cart context to the cart page. Here is my code for the displaying the purchased items to the cart page.

```
export class Cart extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <>
                <div>
                    <h1>Cart</h1>
                </div>
                <CartContext.Consumer>
                    {
                        (cartContext) =>{
                            const {productsToPurchase} = cartContext
                            console.log(productsToPurchase)
                            if (productsToPurchase.length === 0){
                                return(<h1>Cart is empty</h1>)
                            }
                            else {
                                productsToPurchase.map(
                                    (product) =>{
                                        // console.log works fine
                                        console.log("Reached Else Statment")
                                        console.log(product.itemId)
                                        // return doesn't work
                                        return(
                                            <h1 key={product.itemId + "-cart"}> 8525552 </h1>
                                        )
                                })
                            }
                        }
                    }
                </CartContext.Consumer>
            </>
        )
    }

}
```

I have done the same thing and it worked. I have no idea why my mapping function doesn't display the data that I need. Check the comments please for more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a return. You should return the result of productsToPurchase.map()

```
<CartContext.Consumer>
                    {
                        (cartContext) =>{
                            const {productsToPurchase} = cartContext
                            console.log(productsToPurchase)
                            if (productsToPurchase.length === 0){
                                return(<h1>Cart is empty</h1>)
                            }
                            else {
                                return productsToPurchase.map(
                                    (product) =>{
                                        // console.log works fine
                                        console.log("Reached Else Statment")
                                        console.log(product.itemId)
                                        // return doesn't work
                                        return(
                                            <h1 key={product.itemId + "-cart"}> 8525552 </h1>
                                        )
                                })
                            }
                        }
                    }
                </CartContext.Consumer>
```

Comment: But I didn't do that before and it works fine. Why is this?

Comment: This is because in the `else` statement you are calling the `map()` function and then you are returnig the `h1` with the product info for each item but you are not returning anything on the outside function (the one that receives the `cartContext` as you are doing in the `if` statement. So you are not rendering anything in the `else` cases

Comment: I see. Yes the one that worked with me before didn't have the if-else statement. Thank you so much