# ReactJs return does not render components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

The `Console.log(key,_i)` does work, but it does not render any thing.

[return function doesn't render in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913271/return-function-doesnt-render-in-react)

I did try to put one more return following above question, but it does not help.

```js
{newData?.data.forEach((x:any)=> {return (Object.keys(x).map((key:any,_i:number) => {
            console.log(key,_i)
            return (
              <Grid item xs={12}> 
                <TextField 
                  key={_i}
                  style={{ width: "100%" }}
                  required
                  label={key} 
                  onChange={handleOnchange(key)} 
                />
              </Grid> 
              )
          }))})}
```

It is expected to generate a text box. I did try to erase every thing in the `<TextField>` like `key`, `style` ,`required`, `label`, `onChange` . But it still does not work. It is expected to render something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use map instead of forEach

`data.map((x:any)=> {return (Object.keys(x).map(....`

Comment: Can you explain a bit why for each does not work but map work

Comment: when rendering lists in templates, react only support map operator